# Checking "Less than" with a potential very small value in Python

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, matrix

Good morning,
I had to find the `index[i,j]` of the greatest value of a matrix of size `m x n`. The following code works and passes all the test:

```
def biggest_value(matrix, rows, columns):
    max_value = -99999999999999999999
    index = 0
    for i in range(0,rows):
        for j in range(0,columns):
            if max_num < matrix[i][j]:
                max_num = matrix[i][j]
                index = (i,j)
    return index
```

However, since for some of the test the input is very small (ie `-97969584948693858938939848`, I was wondering how could I implement this function in a better way, so I cover any potential negative value the function could take as M argument.

Many thanks!

Comment: What are `m`, `n` and `max_num` in your code? Show us the code you tried.

Comment: Hi Justin, sorry I forgot to update the name of the parameters in the body.
M = matrix
m = num of rows
n = num of columns

Comment: Can you use numpy functions?

Comment: Ideally no, but if there is no easy way of doing it in a different way then that should be ok (nothing was mentioned explicitly when we were given the exercise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `math.inf`

```
import math
def biggest_value(matrix, rows, columns):
    max_num = - math.inf
    index = 0
    for i in range(0,rows):
        for j in range(0,columns):
            if max_num < matrix[i][j]:
                max_num = matrix[i][j]
                index = (i,j)
    return index
```

Answer (score 2):

Using numpy's [`unravel_index`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html) and [`argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html):

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import unravel_index

arr = np.array([[1,23,2,24], [3,45,21,30]])
print(unravel_index(arr.argmax(), arr.shape))
# (1, 1)
```